# Using openconnect on a remote VPS without the ssh session hanging

Tags: ssh, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

I've done a few searches for this one but none of them have any answers for the specific case of openconnect.

I need to access a Cisco AnyConnect VPN, so I'm using openconnect. When I log onto my server and connect, the session freezes and I'm unable to make new connections as well. There's a solution for OpenVPN involving route-nopull I believe, but it doesn't seem like openconnect has such an option. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by following instructions at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237460/ssh-into-a-server-which-is-connected-to-a-vpn-service, to run

```
ip rule add table 128 from <public-ip>
ip route add table 128 to <public ip subnet> dev eth0
ip route add table 128 default via <gateway>
```

where the information was from `ifconfig` and `netstat`. I did not need to do anything else special; I just connected with openconnect as normal.

Comment: This does not work for me which probably means I have determined some of the parameters incorrectly. How do you determine the public ip subnet? Additionally, my gateway is my home router (at least, i think so). Should I use my public IP address in this case, or local network address of the router, or something else entirely?